# Limit messages sent to Slack from Laravel Notification facade

Tags: laravel, notifications, slack

In my app I'm using a notification when something happens.

`Notification::send($users, new ThingStarted($thing));`

This works great. It sends an SMS and an email to each of the users and also, a message to the Slack channel (because you can never have too many notifications right?). The main issue here is that, with multiple users, there's several messages sent to the Slack channel, not just one.

I know I could create an additional notification but it's the same information that's within so another seems superfluous.

Can I stop the `toSlack()` method from firing for each user?

Comment: i think there is a via() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm overthinking it.

I can do

```
Notification::send($users, new ThingStarted($thing));
Notification::send($group, new ThingStarted($thing));
```

and then remove `routeNotificationForSlack` on the `User` model